# what makes this "aside" (in the body of the Q) be 100% height of body height?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the unclear title, 
I just can't figure out exactly what I am asking..

I am learning a lot by seeing the source and "inspecting elements" on any website.

while doing so in  [this site](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/adding-media/) (where I am learning HTML and CSS) I just failed to understand what makes the `<aside>` on the left have 100% height of the body.

it has no rule for "height", and it's content is not big enough to make the div expand so much... (it's content covers maybe 10th of the total height..).

to make it clear which part I am talking about, take a look at the following pictures:

this pic is just to show you where in the doc to look for:
[image: the source of the guilty aside]

and this pic shows the aside in the rendered page (the aside goes all the way down to the bottom of the scroll... please see it in the [site](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/adding-media/) to understand a little better :
[image]

hope you can help me figure it out :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: So where's your wrong code?

Comment: Maybe you need to set it as `position: fixed`

Comment: it is not my code @fish_ball, I am just failing to understand what makes the **aside** have a height of 100%... can you figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that they are using flex-box.
Specifically, the "wrap-micro group" div is the container, and the aside & section elements share the space inside that container.

By default, flex-box is set to hold the inner elements in a row, and the elements will take up all the space provided. this is why you can't see any css properties that hint to what's actually happening.

You can learn more about flex-box through these excellent guides:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I actually suspected the (not familiar to me) flex box thing.
Thanks for the links, I will read about this whole flex thing and try to get my hands on it.

Comment: Glad to help.. btw, when trying to figure out what's going on in a document css-wise, you can try turning off specific properties in the inspector. just hover over the property and tick it off.

Comment: So I did, I turned off almost everything on the aside itself and not much happened (nothing height wise), but I did not think I should turn off properties form the parent as well :). now I know it is also an option that might help me understand the "magics".